# sudoku solving in c++ using class

Tags: c++, arrays

This sudoku solving program is getting compiled but getting error "segmentation fault " please help me in solving this problem and clarify why i am getting segmentation error as i have written every thing properlu .thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

class sudoku
{
public:
    sudoku();
    void initializeSudokuGrid();
    void printSudokuGrid();
    bool solveSudoku();
    bool findEmptyGridSlot(int &row, int &col);
    bool canPlaceNum(int row, int col, int num);
    bool numAlreadyInRow(int row, int num);
    bool numAlreadyInCol(int col, int num);
    bool numAlreadyInBox(int smallGridRow, int smallGridCol, int num);
    int grid[9][9];
};

sudoku::sudoku()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n all the grid locations are initialise to zero";
}

void sudoku::initializeSudokuGrid()
{
    char x = 'y';
    while (x == 'y')
    {
        int row, col, var;
        std::cout
                << "\n enter the row,column and integer in the box(that is 1-9 numbers \n";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cin >> col;
        std::cin >> var;
        grid[row][col] = var;
        std::cout
                << "\n are there any slots that u want to enter the numbers into the boxs enter y else enter n \n";
        std::cin >> x;
    }
}

void sudoku::printSudokuGrid()
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            std::cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

bool sudoku::solveSudoku()
{
    int row, col;
    if (findEmptyGridSlot(row, col))
    {
        for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
        {
            if (canPlaceNum(row, col, num))
            {
                grid[row][col] = num;
                if (solveSudoku()) //recursive call
                    return true;
                grid[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false; //backtrack
    }
    else
        return true; //there are no empty slots
}

bool sudoku::numAlreadyInRow(int row, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (num != 0 && grid[row][i] == num)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool sudoku::numAlreadyInCol(int col, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (num != 0 && grid[i][col] == num)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool sudoku::canPlaceNum(int row, int col, int num)
{
    if (!numAlreadyInRow(row, num))
    {
        if (!numAlreadyInCol(col, num))
        {
            int smallGridRow = row - row % 3;
            int smallGridCol = col - col % 3;
            if (!numAlreadyInBox(smallGridRow, smallGridCol, num))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool sudoku::numAlreadyInBox(int smallGridRow, int smallGridCol, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (grid[i + smallGridRow][j + smallGridCol] == num)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool sudoku::findEmptyGridSlot(int &row, int &col)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
            if (grid[row][col] == 0)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    sudoku s;
    s.printSudokuGrid();
    s.initializeSudokuGrid();
    s.printSudokuGrid();
    std::cout << "\n after solving the problem \n";
    if (s.solveSudoku())
        s.printSudokuGrid();
    else
        std::cout << "\n solution doesnt exist for this type of solution \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, you have not written everything properly. Did you try to debug? Also fix the indentations. The code is not readable.

Comment: This is not how you should ask questions here. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: do you have an output? did you do some debugging? please show what effort you already made to solve the problem yourself, then someone can assist you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mistake in your `findEmptyGridSlot` function

```
bool sudoku::findEmptyGridSlot(int &row, int &col)
{
    for(int row=0;row<9;row++)
    {
        for(int col=0;col<9;col++)
        {
...
```

You're declaring new `int` variables `row` and `col` in the loops, but you probably meant to use the ones passed as parameters.

Remove the `int` keyword to use the parameters instead of declaring new variables:

```
for(row=0;row<9;row++)
{
    for(col=0;col<9;col++)
    {
```